# how to do client side load balancing in spring integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

we can add client-side load balancing in spring boot applications by,

```
@Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        return restTemplate;
    }
```

This will take care of the microservice resolution as well. ie. identifying service by the URL like "http://service_name/api/v1/endpoint/".

Is there any similar mechanism for name resolution in Spring integration?

Comment: Have you tried to inject that `RestTemplate` into your Spring Integration HTTP Channel Adapters? It would be great to see more info where you'd like to have such a load balancing option. Perhaps we would need to introduce a generics `LoadBalancingRequestHandlerAdvice` alongside with an existing `RateLimiterRequestHandlerAdvice`, for example: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan , How can I inject the RestTemplate to the HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this ctor for Spring Integration HTTP Outbound Channel Adapter:

```
/**
 * Create a handler that will send requests to the provided URI using a provided RestTemplate
 * @param uri The URI.
 * @param restTemplate The rest template.
 */
public HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler(String uri, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
```

So, when you configure a `@ServiceActivator` (`handle()` in Java DSL), you just inject your load-balanced `RestTemplate` and everything should work as expected.